# Cascading two Machine Learning models

Tags: machine-learning, pyspark, ddos, network-traffic

I built a machine learning  (ML) model to classify **real-time network traffic** as an attack or normal traffic using a dataset consisting of approximately 3 million records.
Then, I built a second ML model to classify the real-time network traffic according to their application, i.e., Google, Facebook, YouTube, etc. using another dataset consisting of approximately 1.5 million records.

Now I want to **cascade** these **two models** so that if the traffic is normal, then the traffic should be classified by the second ML model. Otherwise, it should be **discarded** since there is no need to pass through the second model.

Can I cascade these two models even though they are built using different datasets? And if so, how can I do that?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I do the cascading logic simply in a programming language code C++ or Python, not using ML-tool features. If the data from the second model, doesn't contribute to the decision of the first model - just keep the models separated.

Comment: Is there any problem in binding or cascading the two models (DDoS and Traffic Classification) even though they are built using different datasets?

Comment: Narrowing the context is always good. Otherwise the ML first should figure out, that the features required for network classification not relevant for DDoS detection.

Comment: So there is no need to chain the two ML models? This is what I understand from your comment.  I edited the question to reflect what I really did.